# How to move classes and functions to a separate file in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good day! I am new to Flutter/Dart. And the more I experiment, the bigger my main file gets. Obviously, I need a separate file in which I will store all the classes and functions that I will refer to in the future.

I have a separate screen with what I need. Here is its code:

```dart
//Internet route
class InternetRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const InternetRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InternetRoute> createState() => _InternetRouteState();
}

class _InternetRouteState extends State<InternetRoute> {
  bool ActiveConnection = false;
  String T = "";
  Future CheckUserConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          ActiveConnection = true;
          T = "Turn off the data and repress again";
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        ActiveConnection = false;
        T = "Turn On the data and repress again";
        showInternetDialog(context);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    CheckUserConnection();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("GeeksforGeeks"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Active Connection? $ActiveConnection"),
          const Divider(),
          Text(T),
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                CheckUserConnection();
              },
              child: const Text("Check"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Alert Dialog about Internet connection
showInternetDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = Center(
    child: TextButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
      },
    ),
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    // title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("Internet connection required"),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
```

I want to create a **my classes.dart** file that will gradually populate with the most commonly used things. In particular, I need **class _InternetRouteState** and **showInternetDialog**.

How to transfer them to a new file? I completely copied the code of that screen. Is it correct? Would that be enough to then refer to them in **main.dart** (after import)? Will all their variables be visible to my screens as well?

**Edit 1.** I don't know how I can move **CheckUserConnection** to my file. I mean I took the piece of code I needed and wrapped it in the **CheckUserConnection class** (in my separate file), but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```dart
class CheckUserConnection {
  bool ActiveConnection = false;
  String T = "";

  Future CheckUserConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          ActiveConnection = true;
          T = "Turn off the data and repress again";
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        ActiveConnection = false;
        T = "Turn On the data and repress again";
        // showInternetDialog(context);   //temporary
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The Problems tab shows the following errors:

```dart
Constructors can't have a return type.
The modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor.
The await expression can only be used in an async function.
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'CheckUserConnection'.
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'CheckUserConnection'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new dart file. Name it internet_dialog_handler.dart. Add this to the file

```dart
class InternetDialogHandler{
//Alert Dialog about Internet connection
showInternetDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = Center(
    child: TextButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
      },
    ),
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    // title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("Internet connection required"),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

In internetRoute use this

```
//Internet route
class InternetRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const InternetRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InternetRoute> createState() => _InternetRouteState();
}

class _InternetRouteState extends State<InternetRoute> {
  bool ActiveConnection = false;
  String T = "";
 InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
  Future CheckUserConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          ActiveConnection = true;
          T = "Turn off the data and repress again";
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        ActiveConnection = false;
        T = "Turn On the data and repress again";
      
  //Use the variable here to access the method in that class 
_internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    CheckUserConnection();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("GeeksforGeeks"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Active Connection? $ActiveConnection"),
          const Divider(),
          Text(T),
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                CheckUserConnection();
              },
              child: const Text("Check"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
class CheckUserConnection {
 
  Future checkInternetAvailability() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Use a different name for the method. Same name is used to defined the constructor of the class. Also make it work independent. Just return a true or false. Now to use this define a variable of type checkUserConnection

```
CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
if(_internetAvailable) 
{
  //do something here;
} else{
  //handle no internet here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I add CheckUserConnection() to this separate file as well? The thing is, I want to check Internet access in different places. In particular, when clicking on particular buttons. So it's important to me that CheckUserConnection() exists for all my code, not just this screen.

Comment: Of course yes. You can also pass a call bavk or widget to show of internet is available. Check how to pass data to a class

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't take CheckUserConnection() and put it into my file. Please tell me what am I doing wrong. My explanations are in Edit1.

Comment: By doesn't work what do you mean please? What's the error?

Comment: I have added all those errors to my Edit1. I just copied the part of the code I needed into a new file and wrapped it in a class. Obviously this is wrong as I get so many errors. But the point is that I only need this part of the code without the widget with buttons and so on.

Comment: Added the answer in Edit section

Comment: Thank you. When I insert bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability(); in main.dart, I get the error: The await expression can only be used in an async function.
What to do?

Comment: In initstate just call a method. And in that method add async and check internrt and set state based on internet availability

Comment: To be honest, I still do not understand what to do. But since this is outside the scope of my original question, that's a different topic. So I consider this issue resolved. Thank you very much for your patience.